# Question about the most probable decay mode

Tags: particle-physics, mesons

I want to understand which of the following possible decay modes for the B$^+$ meson is most probable:

$$ B^+ \rightarrow \tau^+\upsilon_\tau $$

$$ B^+ \rightarrow \mu^+\upsilon_\mu $$

$$ B^+ \rightarrow e^+\upsilon_e $$

I think that it would be the electron as this is a fundamental particle and has the least mass, but I'm not sure and this isn't sufficient explanation. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Wouldn"t the available phase space be the defining factor here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that it would be the electron as this is a fundamental particle and has the least mass

Both are true for the electron, and what is missing in the justification is that  in the other decays  the  [fundamental particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) belong to the same family, leptons, and the interaction entering the calculations of decay is the weak interaction in all three.

Then one can use the fact of the smaller mass to decide that the electron decay is more probable, using the phase space argument as suggested in the comment.